# Retrieving Data from Firebase but cannot show it in listView

Tags: java, android

This is my method to get the data from firebase but the problem is that there is a lot of data that's why it takes a lot of time and did not return the list....

```
public List<Message> retrieveDataFromDatabase() {
    final List<Message> msg = new ArrayList<>();
    Firebase itemsTodo = fb.child("Incomplete");
    itemsTodo.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot children : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : children.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> mapMsg = (Map<String, Object>) child.getValue();
                    boolean isRead = (Boolean) mapMsg.get("read");
                    String message = (String) mapMsg.get("sender");
                    String title = (String) mapMsg.get("title");
                    msg.add(new Message(title, message, isRead));
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });Log.d("Moosa", "Size From Database is "+msg.size());
    return msg;
}`
```

And there is the method to displaying the list view from which i am calling the above method...

```
 public void refreshListItems() {
    Log.d("Moosa", "Invoke Refresh Method");
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<Message>> refresh=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Message>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Message> doInBackground(Void... params) {
          List<Message> msg=db.retrieveDataFromDatabase();
            Log.d("Moosa", "Size is "+msg.size());

            return msg;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Message> messages) {
            Log.d("Moosa", "OnPostExecution Start.......");

            super.onPostExecute(messages);
            final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.emailList);
            final MessageAdapter msgadptr = new MessageAdapter(MainActivity.this, messages);
            list.setAdapter(msgadptr);
            Log.d("Moosa", "OnPostExecuted.......");


        }
    };
    refresh.execute();
    Log.d("Moosa", "Refreshing List...");
}
```

Logs--->
Moosa﹕ Invoke Refresh Method
Moosa﹕ Refreshing List...
Moosa﹕ Size is 0
Moosa﹕ OnPostExecution Start.......
Moosa﹕ OnPostExecuted.......
Moosa: Size From Database is 12

Answer (score 1):

If you observe your logcat order clearly

First it is printing list size 0, but after `onPostExcute(-)` it is returning list size as 12.that means your  `retrieveDataFromDatabase()` is returning empty list and the
`Listener` is loading data in Background so once that loading is completed it is printing list size is 12.

i.e In `onDataChange(-)` only you can add data to your adapter and set it to `ListView`.

Hope this will helps you.